# How do I define a dynamic array in C

Tags: c, arrays

I really don't know how to create a dynamic array in c.
This is a quick example. If I define a static array then a buffer overflow is basically set. So How Do I create a dynamic array which I can use in a for loop? Is malloc a good idea? And if it is, how do i use malloc in a for loop?

```
int my_array[] = {};
int i = 10;
for (i; i <= sizeof(my_array) / sizeof(my_array[0]); i++) {
   my_array[i] = i + 2;
}
```

Comment: This is *undefined behavior*, use either `malloc` or "variable length arrays" (if your compiler supports them)

Comment: @UnholySheep a VLA is **not** "dynamic"...

Comment: There are excellent resources on the web for this.

Answer (score 2):

Not only is `malloc` a good idea, it is the preferred way to dynamically allocate memory in C. The function is defined [here](https://www.codingunit.com/c-reference-stdlib-h-function-malloc), where also an example can be found. Note that `free` should be used to deallocate the memory once it is not needed anymore.

Comment: Also you must not access the memory after `free`ing it.